# How to compare encrypted password in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I already got my password encrypted and store it in database but now I want to compare the encrypted value to the password that a user type upon loading a page. Consider this code:

```
string userName = txtusername.Text;
string password = txtpassword.Text;
Encryptor en = new Encryptor(EncryptionAlgorithm.Rc2, CreateRandomPassword(7));
password = en.Encrypt(password);            
DataTable dt = uMManager.ValidateUser(userName, password);
```

CreateRandomPassword Method

```
private static string CreateRandomPassword(int passwordLength)
{
  string allowedChars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@$?_-";
  char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];
  Random rd = new Random();

  for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
  {
     chars[i] = allowedChars[rd.Next(0, allowedChars.Length)];
  }
  return new string(chars);
}
```

Encryptor Class

```
public class Encryptor
    {
        EncryptEngine engin;
        public byte[] IV;

        public Encryptor(EncryptionAlgorithm algID, string key)
        {
            engin = new EncryptEngine(algID, key);
        }

        public EncryptEngine EncryptEngine
        {
            get
            {
                return engin;
            }
            set
            {
                engin = value;
            }
        }

        public string Encrypt(string MainString)
        {
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(memory, engin.GetCryptTransform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
            streamwriter.WriteLine(MainString);
            streamwriter.Close();
            stream.Close();
            IV = engin.Vector;
            byte[] buffer = memory.ToArray();
            memory.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        }
    }
```

I made a local method to generate random string for RC2 encryption. EncryptionAlgorithm is a Enums for the types of encryption.
Now how can I compare 'password' to the password field in my database to check if the credential is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check if the credential is correct, since you've encrypted it with a key you've thrown away. If you store the key along with the password, the encryption serves no purpose. If you don't, you can't verify.

Instead of trying to create a new way to store passwords, why not use [one of the ways](http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx) that's [known to work](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/creating-salted-hash-values-in-c/)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't encrypt passwords.  Hash them.  Encryption allows for retrieval of the plaintext password, which is a Bad Thing.  Hashing still allows you to check if what the user inputs matches with what he did before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the flow of the program:

- When user register new account -> You encrypt his password -> Save it in database
- When user login -> Encrypt input password -> Get user with password in database -> If user not null -> Login successful -> Else -> Login fail

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are using every time a random key to encrypt your password

so if

> u encrypt "test" the first time 
>  and then u encrypt "test" a
>   second time. the result of the two encryption is not the same.

u should simply use a hash algorithm